# What would be the reasons for not having Jokers in a deck?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

In *Doomtown Reloaded*, it is optional to have Jokers in your deck. However, it seems to me like having Jokers in your deck is extremely useful, since you are more likely to get a better hand in a shootout.

I suppose that not having them in your deck means that there isn't a chance of having an unplayable card in your play hand, but that seems to be a small risk with many options for discarding cards. In fact, I have never played against any player who has *not* had Jokers in their deck, and those whom I have asked have always said it was better to have them.

So what would be the reasons for not having Jokers in a deck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the vast majority of decks do in fact run Jokers.

The main exception is a deck that does not want to get into shootouts at all or make any pulls. This is typically a "Landslide" deck that focuses on playing more dudes & deeds than the opponent can deal with.  It often includes cards like Make the Smart Choice or Pistol Whip, seeking to remove everyone from a posse before it ever gets to comparing Draw Hands. In such a deck a Joker will be a dead card if ever drawn to your Play Hand so there is no point in including them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike original doomtown you cannot discard jokers when you draw them into your play hand. They follow the normal discard rules when drawn in hand. As such, if you have a deck that naturally does well in shootouts and pulls you may find the jokers to be more of a nuisance than a help.

I have a deck that doesn't find the addition of jokers to be helpful. It takes time to cycle cards so jokers can really clog up your hand. While in your hand they provide no value limiting your options for a turn or more while you struggle to discard them.

Comment: Where is the rule that you cannot discard Jokers if they come up in your hand? I don't see any rule like that in the section on Jokers in [the rulebook](https://www.alderac.com/doomtown/2014/04/16/doomtown-reloaded-rulebook/).